# Sonos Cloud API Queues

Tags: sonos

I want to develop a Sonos Controller that is capable of:

Playing a playlist or album now, or next (after currently playing song) or by appending it to the end of the queue.

However I can't see a way to control how the playlist is added to a queue. The documentation at https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/playlists/loadplaylist/ doesn't suggest that it is possible,but there is a reference to the queue in the description for the shuffle playmode "Play the tracks in the queue in a randomly shuffled order."

There is documentation for "Cloud Queues" but this seems to be targeted at Music Services.

Is it possible to create a Cloud Queue that just holds references to tracks in other services?

Not that I would really want to implement that, I would rather just access the queue that is on the players.

Answer (score 2):

The Sonos Control API does not currently allow for direct access to the player queue. Third party integrations can get content on to the queue via the playlists and favorites namespaces, but they can't touch the queue directly.

As you noted, the Cloud Queue API is intended for Content Partners. It is not directly possible to reference third party content in personal CQs, there are authentication issues involved.

Comment: Does loadPlaylist append to the queue, permanently replace the queue, or insert above the queue (the docs don't say)? Which ever of these it does, it seems very limiting to only support that - is there functionality on the way to provide this? Thanks

Comment: The playlist is appended to the current queue, and playback is started there. I'll take your suggestion back to the dev team. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This squares with my user experience of the Sonos queue being very basic and unintelligent.  There have been a number of times I've been forced to clear the queue and start over, rather than being able to reorder items, etc.  FWIW, the closest thing I've seen in their documentation to what it sounds like you're looking for, is under a different API.  Sonos Music API > reorderContainer as documented here: https://developer.sonos.com/reference/sonos-music-api/reordercontainer/

I don't see any similar functionality documented in the Sonos Cloud Queue API.  With regard to random order, I believe that's on playback, not anything that modifies the queue.

Comment: I can't see any way to interact with the queue at all in the API described at https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/. How are you able to clear the queue?